# How to remove and edit object from cookies in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I have a problem with remove and edit cookie object from $cookies in angularjs. I want to make a shop and I am adding products to $cookies global variable with putObject function (I didn't use put because I have more than one argument). I want to add function to remove and edit product from shop and remove and edit only one object from cookie. Please help me!

Here is a fragment of my code (I want to remove/edit object from 'products' cookie):

```
app.controller('Store', ['$scope', '$cookies', 'x2js', '$http', 
    function($scope, $cookies, x2js, $http){

    this.products = $cookies.getObject('products');

    if(!this.products) {
        var self = this;
        $http.get('assets/xml/products.xml').success(function(data) {
            self.products = data.products.product;

            for(var i = 0; i < self.products.length; i++) {
                self.products[i].id = parseInt(self.products[i].id);
                self.products[i].netto = self.products[i].netto + '.00';
                self.products[i].tax = parseInt(self.products[i].tax);
                self.products[i].brutto = parseFloat(self.products[i].brutto);
                self.products[i].rating = parseInt(self.products[i].rating);
            };
        });
    }

    $scope.product = $cookies.getObject('product') || {};

    $scope.$watch('product', function() {
        $cookies.putObject('product', $scope.product);
    }, true);

    this.addProduct = function() {
        if(this.countCategories() >= 2) {
            if(this.validateForm()) {

                var product = {
                    id: this.products.length + 1,
                    name: $scope.product.name,
                    code: $scope.product.code,
                    image: $scope.product.image,
                    netto: this.intToFloat($scope.product.netto, 2),
                    tax: $scope.product.tax,
                    brutto: this.calculatePriceBr(),
                    rating: parseInt(this.ratingChecked()),
                    category: this.categoryChecked(),
                    option: this.optionChecked(),
                    selected: $scope.product.selected
                };

                this.products.push(product);

                $scope.product = {};

                $cookies.putObject('products', this.products);

                $('#product-add').modal('hide');
                return true;
            } else {
                return;
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    };
 })();
```

Comment: Hi, you are getting an error now, it's just working, or want to know how to do it? Regards!

Comment: I was trying to do this for many ways, but it isn't working for me and I didn't have any result :( I would like to know how to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

I've made a little test based on your code (simplified):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);


app.controller('Store', Store);


Store.$inject = ['$scope', '$cookies', '$http'];

function Store($scope, $cookies, $http) {

  var vm = this;
  vm.products = [];
  vm.cart = [] ;
  vm.inCookie =[];

  $http.get('products.xml').success(function(data) {
    vm.products = data;

    for (var i = 0; i < vm.products.length; i++) {
      vm.products[i].id = parseInt(vm.products[i].id);
      vm.products[i].netto = vm.products[i].netto + '.00';
      vm.products[i].tax = parseInt(vm.products[i].tax);
      vm.products[i].brutto = parseFloat(vm.products[i].brutto);
      vm.products[i].rating = parseInt(vm.products[i].rating);
    };
  });


  this.addProduct = function(row) {


    vm.cart.push(row);


    $cookies.put('cart', JSON.stringify(vm.cart));

    vm.inCookie = JSON.parse($cookies.get('cart'));

  };

}
```

You can see here how to add and retrieve data from a cookie.

In this plunkr you can see it working.

https://plnkr.co/edit/ew1ePjzbMxjAqtgx8hzq?p=preview

Hope this helps.

Regards!

Comment: I was looking for something different but I solve my problem :) Thanks for your help and reply!